# Replace 5400 RPM drive with 7200 RPM?

Tags: hard-drive, sony-vaio

I have a Sony PCG-71211W laptop with an internal Western Digital 500 GB 5400 RPM 3.0Gb/s drive (WD5000BEVT). The hard drive crashed and I need to replace it.

Can I replace it with a 7200 RPM drive? I wasn't sure if the computer could handle the faster drive or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It will be fine.  All things equal, a 7200 RPM HD will just eat up more power.